# Why this "Error: Pattern matching error: no pattern matches value {"arch":"x64","distro":"rhel"}" appears whenever I run "npx prisma (some command)"?

Tags: linux, fedora, prisma

Whenever I run **npx prisma (some other command)** I got that error (Error: Pattern matching error: no pattern matches value {"arch":"x64","distro":"rhel"}).
I don't understand what can be the problem. My application still is running properly.
Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

I googled it and the answers I found suggest that there are some incompatibility somewhere over my application between some dependence, or thing related, and my operating system. However, I am not really sure about this but it can be a clue. If any other technical information be necessary to resolve this, comment here and I will display it.

Comment: Which version of Prisma are you using? Is this happening on the latest version i.e. 4.8.0?

Comment: @Nurul_Sundarani, I could not check what version I am really using through terminal, since the command npx prisma version also throws me that error. However, reading my package.json and package-lock.json, there are some references to prisma, as dependences, and one of my "@prisma/client" has the version 4.8.0. So, I really think that the lastest version is the one installed on my machine.

Comment: I do not really know what I did but the problem was solved. As you asked me my prisma version, I have the idea to change it to an older version so I googled it. I found [https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/faq/keep-prisma-server-and-cli-in-sync-fq07/](this) and then ran some commands. Maybe this prisma1 has something to do with the solved problem. I will left here all the commands I ran: `npm install prisma@4 @prisma/client@4`,  `npx prisma1 --version` , `npm uninstall -g prisma1@1.34.12`. After that, everything went well.